# JQuery takes the wrong value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

An easy question for you I think :-)

```
<form id="upload" method="post" name="form">  
<input id="id<?php echo $a; ?>" class="id" name="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $id_submit; ?>" >
<input style="margin-top:-5px;width:29px;" class="submit" type="image" src="save.jpg">
</form>
```

The source code looks e.g. like this:

**Form 1:**

```
<form id="upload" method="post" name="form">  
<input id="id1" class="id" name="id" type="text" value="12345" >
<input style="margin-top:-5px;width:29px;" class="submit" type="image" src="save.jpg">
</form>
```

**Form 2:**

```
<form id="upload" method="post" name="form">  
<input id="id2" class="id" name="id" type="text" value="65432" >
<input style="margin-top:-5px;width:29px;" class="submit" type="image" src="save.jpg">
</form>
```

After click on save.jpg it calls my jquery-function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                              
                           $( "#upload" ).on("submit", function(e) {

                               e.preventDefault();

                                               var id = $('.id').val();
                                               …..
```

The problem is that when I click on save.jpg in the form 2, then it takes the value **12345** instead of **65432**.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you have two forms on the same page with the same ID?

Comment: You want to find the id in the containing form.  Replace `var id = $('.id').val() with `var id = $(this).find('.id').val();`

Comment: j08691: Yes, that is right. I have more than one form with the same id on the same page. cale_b: That does not work! :-(

Answer (score 2):

the form is needs to be unique

`<form id="upload" method="post" name="form">`

thats why it takes the first element found in the dom structure with the target `id`, change the id of the second form .

Also when you do

`var id = $('.id').val();`

there a more than one element with the given class. you can try this instead

`var id = $(this).find('.id').val();`

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks dreamweiver. var id = $(this).find('.id').val(); does not work unfortunately. Now, the jquery-function takes nothing. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Use a broader selector to target both forms then find the id of the current submitted form:

```
$( "form" ).on("submit", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).find('.id').val();//"this" is the current form
```

Answer (score 0):

That works:

```
var id = $(this).('.id').val();
```

Thanks for your help guys.